# add a ligne seperator between days dhtmlx scheduler

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I'm building a calendar with scheduling funcionalities using the `dhtmlx` library, i was wondering if it is possible to put a vertical seperator between each day .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice to get more information. There are borders between days in DHTMLX Scheduler by default.
If you want to highlight them, it is possible using CSS. Please, check the sample link: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/2b8e0d86